# ESP Manual LED off status update on android app

Tags: android, firebase, esp8266

I'm a beginner in this field. I have developed an android app through which I can control the LED's connected to the GPIO pins of ESP Wi-Fi module. That app is connected to Firebase to save the status of the buttons. Everything works fine.

Now I want to implement the followings:

1. I want, if I manually switch off the LED by removing the GPIO pin of respective LED, that status "LED OFF" should be updated on my app.
2. I want to add Fan speed controller

For first bullet point, should I use firebase too?

Please suggest the tutorial and ways I can achieve both.

Comment: Some of my devices have a web api for control (I just use postman, didn't write an app) and they report out on a web page and/or Thingspeak.  I save settings in a file right on the device using SPIFFS.

Comment: Your Firebase is updating from App, now you have to hit API(Server side coding which will update your Firebase), when any node is updated from Manual flow then you must have Event listeners implemented in your App which will listen changes.

Answer (score 0):

Number 1:

**Reading digital output states on an ESP8266**

You cannot read and write the same pin without blinking the light as you alter `pinMode` on the fly. The easiest way is to connect another GPIO as the cathode of the LED, and set that pin's `pinMode` to `INPUT`. you can then *digitalRead* that input to determine if the LED is present *and* on (`1`) or not (`0`).

That only works well on red low-power LEDs though, since the GPIOs only handle 12ma officially. You'll likely want to use something like NPN transistors to deliver VCC to them, in which case you can connect the input pin to the LED anode via a 5-10k resistor, and the LED cathode to GND.

In terms of pushing that status to the update, you can poll every few hundred ms, checking that each read value one is the same as the last, and sending the change off to sparkfun when found. Store the state in a global and compare to the read.

You can also use an interrupt instead of polling. These are more performant and complicated, so for very low-frequency events like LED status, polling suffices and is arguably easier to code from scratch. Do look into interrupts eventually though, they are powerful on single-threaded devices.

Number 2:

**Controlling fan speed with an ESP8266**

You need a PWM circuit to control a DC motor's fan speed. There's many relatively simple circuits using mosfets to connect and disconnect the ground of the fan very quickly, thus averaging its used power as a ratio of maximum power. The ratio is set using `analogWrite` with a pin # and a int from `0` to `1024`.

Note that your fan probably won't spin if the written value is less than 350; there's not enough voltage at those low values.  Also, i'd recommended boosting the PWM frequency to super-sonic levels using `analogWriteFreq(16000);` in `setup()` to avoid fan noise.  If you can get a 12v DC 4-wire PC cooling fan, you can actually hook the pwm input line to the control GPIO and not have to wire any circuits.

If your fan runs on AC, it's a lot more complicated and dangerous. The simplest circuits use an IGBT transistor to achieve "PWM" on an AC signal, but triacs+diacs, and random-cross solid state relays work well if you manage your own cross timing. Make sure you handle motor impedance as well. Complicated? you bet.

I have found that it's easer and cheaper to modify an existing and cheap fan controller like [this one](http://www.ebay.com/itm/112236110672), de-soldering the large potentiometer and replacing with an [LDR](http://www.ebay.com/itm/262136737294). The pot's used as a variable resistor, not a voltage divider, so it's easy to mimic. You can then tape an LED to the LDR, hook the LED to a GPIO output, and then use `analogWrite()` to control the AC output. Experiment with LED resistor values to maximize precision and linearity, though for a fan, even just three usable levels would be an improvement.  The opto-isolation from the ESP to main is a nice feature of this cheap method.

If you have an existing commercial multi-speed fan with a few levels, like a ceiling fan or a box fan, you can replace the fan's switch/knob with relays to mimic a human selecting a switch position. You have to reverse-engineer which wires are "hot or not" under the different selections. It's mains AC, so do be careful doing that...

Comment: Thank you for your answer but the one you answered for my first question, I know I need to add resistor and monitor the status of the LED but I want that Status of the LED to be updated to my android App's Firebase account. Is that possible?

Comment: you should be able to use their http api and the ESP's HTTPClient library to push the data from the ESP. If they don't have an easy api, just make your own simple one with node.js; talk from the ESP to node and from node to firebase.

Comment: Can you please post a snippet?